# Why -ing was used in those sentences?

Tags: gerunds

Why **skate** was used with -ing in those sentences?

> I plan to go **skating** at the local park.
>
> Cool! I’ve never been into **skating** myself, but I have some friends who love it. Watch out for slips, trips and falls.

P.S. is this sentence correct?

> *Why skate was used with -ing in those sentences*?

Comment: You need to put the auxiliary verb *was* in front of the Subject to make a question. --> "Why was -ing used in these sentences?"

Comment: "Go to skate" does not sound correct in this context, though.  "I plan to go skating" or "I plan to go skate" sound fluent; "I plan to go to skate" does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'Skating'** here is an occupation (activity).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skating

Other examples:

- I will do cooking.
- I will go swimming.
- I am into driving mostly.
- I was never good in hiking.

P.s. Why was (the word) **'skate'** used with **'-ing'** in those sentences?